# GDS- expedia - booking.com

Tags: php

Can anyone show me the way or provide some good links to read in order to
send hotel availability from a reservation system to GDS networks -  expedia booking.com

Do i have to make something like a xml file?
Any API available in php?

thanks for any hint-help!!!

Comment: The question is not very clear IMO. If you don't provide more information, this question might get closed because it sounds a bit too 'sendmetehcodezplz'

Comment: I've worked with such systems. You need to sign a contract with those services. After this, you'll get access to their web service documentation. APIs are usually not available because the contract costs serious money.

Comment: tharkun: yes my question maybe is not so clear becouse i dont know what exactly should i ask.
I did't request any code, i want some directions how i can achieve this.

Ionut G. Stan: so i must contact direct seperately expedia,booking.com etc or is 'universal' format that they accept?
can u provide me a link?

thanks you all again for your time.

Comment: You should talk to them. Most of the time, every vendor has its own XML format. There is an XML standard for the travel business, called Open Travel, which is lead by the Open Travel Alliance: http://www.opentravel.org/ Anyway, few vendors implement the OTA standard, so don't count on that.

Answer (score 4):

As Ionut G. Stan said, there is XML standard that few OTA (Online Travel Agents) are using and for beginning you could use this standard in your development process.

Because Booking.com is currently OTA No.1, you can start with these links:

http://distribution-xml.booking.com/

http://distribution-xml.booking.com/affiliates/documentation/

http://xml.booking.com/affiliates/documentation/xml_general.html

After that will connecting with other OTAs be much easier and it will use similar principles.

And to make clear one more thing. GDS (Global Distribution System) (like Sabre, Amadeus, Galileo,...) are different than OTAs (Booking.com, Expedia, HRS,...).